# Google OAUTH: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I'm trying to use the goolge-oauth2 library, and when i call the refresh token method on the class I have this error:

Caused by:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport.buildRequest(NetHttpTransport.java:152)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport.buildRequest(NetHttpTransport.java:55)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:889)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:441)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:157)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refreshIfExpired(OAuth2Credentials.java:174)
```

This is the code I use to retrieve the ServiceAccountCredentials object

```java
ServiceAccountCredentials googleCredential = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromPkcs8(client_id, client_email, private_key,private_key_id, Arrays.asList(scope));
googleCredential.refreshIfExpired();
```

using "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam" as scope

now this is the first time i need to connect to an Https url so maybe i'm missing something...

Comment: What kind of software are you developing? The missing class is part of the JRE, but if you are developing e. g. a OSGi plugin, access to it might be restricted. So the context you're working in might be relevant here.

Comment: i'm working on an OSGI plugin, on jboss fuse platform, so this can explain also the fact that when I tested with a main class it worked from my local eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1072090/ says you need to import javax.net.ssl in your manifest. I'm not an OSGi developer so I'm not sure how *exactly* that works but it shouldn't be too hard to find documentation on that.